# How to disable Activities on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, macos

I've created a Virtual Machine on my iMac(running Catalina 10.15.7). The VM is running Ubuntu 20.04.3 AMD64 with 4GB of RAM. when using the VM, Ubuntu randomly enters me into the Activities panel without me touching the Activities button.

Is there a gesture/shortcut or something that does this? If so, how can I disable it?

Comment: It's called the "[Activities Overview](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-activities-overview.html.en)" in GNOME (assuming that you are running GNOME), not "Activities Menu" nor "Activities Panel". Please note that I'm not deliberately trying to be pedantic, but it just helps to accurately reference UI elements when seeking help. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm running GNOME yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The `⌘` key seems to do it. I just need to escape the VM before using `⌘`+`⇥` to change windows.